# Getting a page's complete source using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to capture and post all JS errors in a page to a Django view. I'm doing something like this.

```
<script>
    window.onerror = function(errorMsg, file, lineNumber) {
        post_data = {error: errorMsg, file: file, 
        location: window.location.href, lineNumber: lineNumber,
        ua: navigator.userAgent};
        jQuery.post('/js_errors/', post_data);
    }
</script>
```

**The Question:** I'd like to add the actual line as well. How do I get the line from the page source, given the line number?

So far, I've tried this (accounting for all kinds of newline characters):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML.split(/\r?\n/)[lineNumber];
```

However, this doesn't give me the correct line number. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did u capture header data as well ?

Comment: why do u need the line number?

Comment: I am assuming u wud be analysing this on an interface backend. Why not do the splitting there?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Why on earth would you delay splitting of a string til it hits the server? You'd be transferring an abundance of unwanted data.

Comment: @DarkBee: Ah, I suppose I didn't, DOCTYPE and all. How do I get the *complete* page source?

Comment: my bad. I thought he wanted to send the source marked with line number

Comment: @Alxandr: +1. It would be too expensive to send all of my HTML back to the server just to parse it for a line. I want to do this client-side.

Comment: @GPX Did you try with `lineNumber` `+`/`-` `1` after the split? I'm not sure what `lineNumber` in the `onerror` function is, but it might not be 0-indexed.

Comment: @Alxandr: I did! It's still giving me a line that's 3 (or 5 in some instances) linebreaks away from the offending line.

Comment: use document.documentElement.outerHTML/innerHTML

Comment: @GPX In most cases `'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<body>\n' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '\n</body>'` should probably get you there. However, the problem arises if you have spacing before doctype or between doctype and body.

Comment: @JanithChinthana: Thanks, I tried both, and they all give me the same result! The `split` of `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`, `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, `document.documentElement.innerHTML` all give me the same wrong line.

Comment: @Alxandr That's what I'm thinking too. Is there a method to detect that?

Comment: @GPX I don't think so. But never say never.

Comment: @GPX If you're using jQuery can you not just read the response from `$.post("")` - sure there's a bit of network overhead, but probably the only reliable way to get the real full source

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly efficient, but should get what you're after (i.e. doctype and all):

```
lineNumber = 23;
errorLine = null;
$.post("",function(source) {
    errorLine = source.split(/\r?\n/)[lineNumber];
});
```

Answer (score -4):

use jquery method $('#divID_where_you_want_to_extract).load('url');